# How to blur images in bulk?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, automation, blur

I have an HTML theme and to avoid copyright issues I want to blur all images so my clients can use it freely. There are 50 images, I need some tool that is free and have the ability to blur images significantly.

For example, with css you can blur several images at the same time, with a blur of at least 5px I'm done.

Comment: Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: I don't get it. Why can't you just blur the images in Photoshop? Or use ImageMagick? Or are you wanting to blur them in bulk on the site itself?

Comment: Just put in your theme css _img{filter:blur(5px) !important}_ and that should do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows I would use IrfanView

File > Batch Conversion Rename

On the window that opens there is an advanced options dialog. You can blur them there.

It has an option to put the new files on a specific new folder, but please backup your original files first.

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend you use css for blur your images with `{ filter:blur(5px) !important }`, because anyone with some css knownledge can easy take the image for free editing the css with the element inspector on any Browser, like this example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #test { filter:blur(5px) !important }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="test" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=World&font=lobster">
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the images of the result and editing with the development tools that Firefox have.
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

So if you don't want your images to be stolen so easy you should directly upload the image blurred with some software like GIMP, Photoshop or any photo editos. But if you want something simple, easy, and for free I would recommend you this website, you select the link or upload the image, adjust the blur click apply and save it, no watermarks is free!!. Hope it helps you

**Link -->** [Editor Online To Blur Images](https://www110.lunapic.com/editor/?action=blur)